# Magento 2: Image Upload JS Validation

Tags: magento2, image, validation, form-validation

I'm going to upload one image. I need to put below validations on Client side & Server Side

- Allowed file formats: jpeg, jpg, png
- Max. File Size is 5MB.
- Image size should be 100 Width x 100 height

**lib\web\mage\validation.js**

From above file, not able to achieve this.

**app\code\Custom\Module\Block\MyPost\Edit.php**

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value=""  data-validate="{required:true}" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We should create new validation classes: `validate-filesize`, `validate-fileextensions` & `validate-image-height-width`.

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($) {
    //Validate Image FileSize        

    $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-filesize', function (v, elm) {
                var maxSize = 5 * 102400;
                if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                    if (elm.value) {
                        var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                        var e = oas.getFile(elm.value);
                        var size = e.size;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (elm.files[0] != undefined) {
                        size = elm.files[0].size;
                    }
                }
                if (size != undefined && size > maxSize) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }, $.mage.__('The file size should not exceed 5MB'));

    //Validate Image Extensions

    $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-fileextensions', function (v, elm) {

                var extensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'];
                if (!v) {
                    return true;
                }
                with (elm) {
                    var ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                    for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                        if (ext == extensions[i]) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }, $.mage.__('Disallowed file type.'));

    //Validate Image Width and Height

    $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-image-height-width', function (v, elm) {

                if (!v) {
                    return true;
                }
                with (elm) {
                    var file, img;
                    if ((file = elm.files[0])) {
                        img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function () {
                            var height = this.height,
                                    width = this.width;
                            if (height > 100 || width > 100) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            return true;
                        };
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }, $.mage.__('Height and Width must not exceed 100px.'));
});
```

I followed a guide to create the script above: https://gist.github.com/obukhow/5040981

Comment: Thanks @Khoa. For Image Height & Width Validation?

Comment: I updated the new case, however, not yet test. If there is any error, let's me know.

Comment: @khoa where I have to add this above code. Please specify the location as well.

Comment: Thanks, @KhoaTruongDinh it's a great solution.