# MagenImage Upload File Extention JS Validation?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3, validation

I'm new to Magento 2.3, i want to validate file upload field.

- Allowed file formats: jpeg.

I put a method in **lib\web\mage\validation.js**

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function ($) {
    //Validate Image Extensions

    $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-fileextensions', function (v, elm) {

                var extensions = ['jpeg'];
                if (!v) {
                    return true;
                }
                with (elm) {
                    var ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                    for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                        if (ext == extensions[i]) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }, $.mage.__('Disallowed file type.'));
});
```

and add this class `validate-fileextensions` in file > input, in this file `app\code\{vendor_name}\{module_name}\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab\Main.php`

```
        $fieldset->addField(
            'filename',
            'image',
            [
                'label' => __('File'),
                'title' => __('File'),
                'name' => 'filename',
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'class' => 'validate-fileextensions'
            ]
        );
```

but its not working for me, also when i inspect on file > input, i can't see my custom class their. see below image.
[image]

Comment: do you want to put validation into your custom controll from admin configuration?

Comment: please don't mind I'm very new to magento, i have a form in adminpanel, in that form their is a file type field, i just want to validate its extention. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: only validate .jpeg formats images??

Comment: Brother @RkRathod, Actually all these `['jpg','jpeg','gif','png','csv','xlsx']`

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya Answer is correct any issue of that code

Comment: Yes...! his answer is correct but i need to do it with frontend not on `POST`.... `JS Validation` @Rk Rathod

Comment: validate with js ???

Comment: yes, i just want to stop user on frontend, if he/she upload other extention file, if their is another way except `JS`, then no issue.... @RkRathod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93428/discussion-between-rk-rathod-and-saif-zakir).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the validation into your controller, which save the value of this field like this.

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    ...
) {
    ......
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    .....
}

public function execute()
{
    try {
            $destinationFolder = 'PATH OF FOLDER WHERE YOU NEED TO UPLOAD FILE';
            $yourInputFileName = 'YOURFILEUPLOADFIELDNAME';

            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(array('fileId' => $yourInputFileName));

            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
            return $result['file'];

    } catch (\Exception $e) {             
            throw new FrameworkException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**NOTE** `$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);` in this line you can specify which file type you need to allowed.

Comment: i have `app\code\{vendor_name}\{module_name}\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\Index\Save.php`, should i put this code in that file ... ? @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: Yes, you can validate file there and show error message according to that.

Comment: Ok let me try :)

Comment: I already write the comment that, this is the path of folder where you upload the files into magento.

Comment: After adding this line `\Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,` i get an error something like this... `1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor etc...` @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: its validating but on post, i need to validate it on frontend.....

Comment: Yes, that I already told that it validate on controller of post.

Comment: did you know how to do it through frontend ... ? @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf']); takes only pdf, if other are uploaded i need to show error message, how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link :-](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134387/magento-2-image-upload-js-validation)

**Try This :-**

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'filename',
            'file',
            [
                'label' => __('File'),
                'title' => __('File'),
                'name' => 'filename',
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Bro with you code user can still upload other extention file... @RkRathod

Comment: which extension file upload???

Comment: your code let me upload all file extenton, when i click on `all file` when `file manager` opens....

Comment: try this code..

Comment: yeah exactly, before raising this question, i applied `file` tag instead of image `image` but my senior told me to keep `image` tag, coz it has a preview feature and  checkbox delete feature... In Magento core elements, their is a `Image.php` file which belongs to this `image` tag, and it has a built-in class, i think `input-file`... I also saw many answers for applying custom class in `Image` tag but they all were very old question so i couldn't understand it... @RkRathod

Comment: so working your functionality ???

Comment: Sorry.... ??? @RkRathod

Comment: No, it didn't work, as i told you, the answers i saw was very old and it's difficult for me to understand with new Magento....

Comment: "validate-fileextensions" is default class for validate your file extension

Comment: yeah its a default class but we can't gave it like this `'class' => 'validate-fileextensions',` for `image file field`, maybe their is another way to give class to it.

Comment: but you can chnge type "image" to "file"

Comment: yeah i can, but i need a checkbox feature to delete file on edit form, and a small thumbnail to preview, you can see image attach in question....

Comment: ohk i will check

Comment: i also search for old answers which i was talking about and will give you its link....

Comment: Take a look at this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84306/admin-form-validation-making-image-file-upload-required .... **also see all the links in this answer**