# Magento 2: Image Field Checkbox Not Working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, image-upload, custom-field

I'm new to Magento, i have a `image field`, when i upload image and edit it, like next time i want to remove the uploaded image, i checked the checkbox and hit the save button, but image do not delete, `I WANT TO DELETE IMAGE WHEN CHECKBOX CHECKED.`

Here is my image field:

```
        $fieldset->addField(
            'filename',
            'image',
            [
                'label' => __('File'),
                'title' => __('File'),
                'name' => 'filename',
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
            ]
        );
```

**\app\code\EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save.php**

```
<?php
namespace EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        // \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
        )
    {
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $pathurl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'customimport/';
        $mediaDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
        $mediapath = $this->_mediaBaseDirectory = rtrim($mediaDir, '/');

        if(!empty($_FILES['filename']['name'])){
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'filename']);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg','jpeg','gif','png','csv','xlsx']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $path = $mediapath . '/customimport/';
            $result = $uploader->save($path);
        }
        $currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('EC\Customimport\Model\Customimport');

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customimport_id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }

            // =============UPDATED CODE=============
            if(!empty($_FILES['filename']['name'])){
              $model->setData('filename', $_FILES['filename']['name']);
            }
            elseif(isset($data['filename']['delete'])){
                $model->setData('filename', null);
            }

            $model->setData('title', $data['title']);
            $model->setData('status', $data['status']);
            $model->setData('created_time', $currenttime);
            $model->setData('update_time', $currenttime);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Item detail has been saved.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['customimport_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the entry.'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['customimport_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('customimport_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please attach your save.php file

Comment: Question Updated @RkRathod

Comment: check answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add This Condition in `save.php` file :-**

> Add This Code After **`if ($data) {`**

```
            if(!empty($_FILES['filename']['name'])){
              $model->setData('filename', $_FILES['filename']['name']);
            }
            elseif(isset($data['filename']['delete'])){
                $model->setData('filename', null);
            }
```

Comment: It's not working bro :( @Rk Rathod

Comment: in which position add this code ?

Comment: Check Updated Answer @Rk Rathod

Comment: check checkbox and show in print $data

Comment: and check any array generate like this "filename['delete']"

Comment: i did `print_r($data)` but getting an error. `Undefined property: EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor::$model in C:\xampp\htdocs\crimson-local\app\code\EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save.php on line 56`

Comment: `$filename = $this->model['filename'];` is undefined property...

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: working or not????

Comment: No, it didn't work :( Please see updated question for 'before `check` & 'after check' `print_r`...... @Rk Rathod

Comment: where is issue your file name is NULL means image is deleted

Comment: I don't know, i get `filename` as `NULL` but in my `phpmyadmin` filename is still their..... :/

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: yup see updated question now its working.... :) after `if($data)` code....

Comment: if answer usefull then up vote thank you happy coding :)

Comment: could you help me on this too .... ? @Rk Rathod
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273660/magenimage-upload-file-extention-js-validation

Comment: ya sure let me check

Comment: Bro @RkRathod please help me out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276387/magento-2-custom-js-not-working-when-adding-more-than-1-js

Comment: ohk let me check